# Compass not working on Doogee T6

Tags: orientation, compass, doogee

I have a new smartphone: Doogee T6. According to Sensor Box, it has both a magnetic sensor and an accelerometer sensor.

[image: Image from Sensor Box for Android]

My installed spirit level works fine, but no compass app seems to work.

Any ideas as to how I can get a working compass... and if possible a working AR on Pokemon Go where it tells me that it does not detect the orientation of the phone :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, I assume, your phone does **not** have a magnetic compass.

Some sources do confirm this assumption:

- http://www.devicespecifications.com/en/model/fb273756 (under "Sensors")
- http://www.doogeemobile.com/doogee-t6.html (scroll down to *Ken*'s question)

Comment: Well, that's my conclusion too :-) Some page says it has compass, some says not - that's why I tried the app and asked in here as well